# How to get the length of an array with out empty value?

Tags: c#

I'm now doing a project about solving a Magic cube problem.  I want to create an array to remember the steps like this:

```
char[] Steps = new char[200];
```

Each time I do the 'F','B','R','L','U','D' turn method, it will add a 'F','B','R','L','U','D' character in the array.
But when I want to get the length of the steps, it always shows 200.

for example:

```
char[] steps = new char[5];
```

and now I've already added 3 steps:

```
steps[] = {'f','b','f','',''};
```

How can I get the length '3'?

Or is there any alternative method I can use that I don't need to set the length at the beginning?

Comment: why not using just a List<char>

Comment: The length of an array is fixed - it is the number of "slots" in it, empty or not.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as '' is not allowed for characters. The concept of an 'empty character' makes no sense unless you define it.. you could use char(0) and then `Count()` all exluding those..

Comment: @CharlesBretana: That wouldn't compile. `''` isn't a valid character literal.

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer: a list fits the situation better than an array. However, I can't help noticing that in order to add the steps to an array in the "next" position you already must be keeping track of how many steps have been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you  can just use `List<char>` but if performance is really critical in your sceanario  you  can just initialize the initial capacity

something like the following

```
List<char> list  = new List<char>(200);
list.Add('c');
list.Add('b');
```

here count will return just what you have really added

```
var c = list.Count;
```

note in list you can apply `Linq Count()` or just use the `Count` property which does not need to compute like `Linq` and return  the result immediately

Answer (score 2):

You will get compilation error on this line

```
steps[] = {'f','b','f','',''};
```

As you cannot use empty char and you need to write steps instead of steps[].
I will suggest you to use string array instead and using LINQ get count of not empty elements in this way:

```
string [] steps = {"f","b","f","",""};
Console.WriteLine(steps.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Count());
```

Comment: Whilst this does answer the question, I would still follow BRAHIM Kamel's advice and use a list instead of an array which are of fixed sizes.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Yeah, I do agree with you, but he was asking about arrays and not lists

Comment: I know, you answered his question correctly. Was more of a tip for OP :D

Comment: You can just use 
`steps.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))`

Answer (score 0):

To count non-empty items using `System.Linq`:

```
steps.Count(x => x != '\0');
```

Your code doesn't compile since `''` isn't allowed as a `char`, but I'm assuming that you mean empty elements in a `char` array which are actually represented by `'\0'` or the Unicode Null. So the above condition simply counts the non null items in your array.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a list of character that would make things a lot simpler like this :

```
List<char> steps = new List<char>();
```

and just add a line to the list for each steps :

```
char move = 'F';
steps.add(move);
```

finally then you can count the number of move in the list easily

```
int numberofmove = steps.count();
```